# Try to parse JSON Array of Arrays on Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, codable

Here is the json code:

```json
{
  
    "rows":
        [[{
            "text":"some text",
            "type":{
                "type":"inlineUrl",
                "url":"https://nothing.com"
            }
        }],
        [{
            "text":"some text",
            "type":{
                "type":"inlineCallback",
                "data":"some data"
            }
        },
        {
            "text":"some text",
            "type":{
                "type":"inlineCallback",
                "data":"some data"
            }
        }
        ]]
        
}
```

A more abbreviated would look like:
Rows = [ [Row1], [Row2, Row3] ]

And I'm trying to get it to work like this:

```swift
struct ReplyHandler: Codable {
    let rows: [RowsHandler]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rows
    }
}

struct RowsHandler: Codable {
    let row1: [RowHandler]
    let row2: [Row2Handler]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case row1
        case row2
    }
}

struct RowHandler: Codable {
    let text: String
    let type: TypeHandler
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "type"
        case text = "text"
    }
}

struct Row2Handler: Codable {
    let row1: RowHandler
    let row2: RowHandler

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case row1
        case row2
    }
}

struct TypeHandler: Codable {
    let type: String
    let url: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "type"
        case url = "url"
    }
    
}
```

But Xcode compiler gives this error:

> Expected to decode String but found an array instead.

Don't understand how to properly nest other arrays in the array

While posting my question, I noticed that the arrays in "type" are different: the first row have url, the second and third have data, but anyway, it's not a point.

Comment: *enough information*? No, for example what issues do you have? And what **is** the question? The structs cannot work, For example where is the key `row1` in the JSON?

Comment: You haven't asked a question or in a clear way described what your problem is and please remove the last paragraph all together

Comment: Sorry, my first posting. Did not fully figured out how to objectively place the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your model to something like this:

```
struct ReplyHandler: Codable {
    let rows: [[RowHandler]]
}

struct RowHandler: Codable {
    let text: String
    let type: TypeHandler
}

struct TypeHandler: Codable {
    let type: String
    var url: String?
    var data: String?
}
```

Notice that `url` and `data` properties in `TypeHandler` are optionals to cover both cases.

Comment: Thank you so much :)
It really MUCH shorter, but the main thing is that it WORKS

Comment: Don't really understand...can you please explain, how and why this model divide [[ ]] (double square quotes array) into two different arrays [ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3 ] ], and it works as it should? We don't explicitly divide them.

Comment: @DobrySiabar the `rows` key is of type array of arrays of `RowHandler` (`[[RowHandler]]` or even better `Array<Array<RowHandler>>`) An array can contain variable amount of elements. In your example (`[ [ 1 ], [ 2, 3 ] ]`) the outer array contains 2 element. The first of it's elements is an array that contains only one while the second is an array that contains 2.

Comment: @DobrySiabar you can look for better explanations and examples about [Collection Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html) in the official swift documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Although manual JSON parsing is useful I think that it must be much easier to use tool like this https://app.quicktype.io/ to convert JSON into Swift classes or structs

For you JSON it provides this result

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let rows: [[Row]]
}

// MARK: - Row
struct Row: Codable {
    let text: String
    let type: TypeClass
}

// MARK: - TypeClass
struct TypeClass: Codable {
    let type: String
    let url: String?
    let data: String?
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this tool with much bigger JSON piece of code, had a lot of errors. Did not think to cut the code there :(